# LINQ: Combine join with left join

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Let's say I have this query in SQL:

```
SELECT
    ....
FROM
   TableA a
   JOIN TableB b on a.Id = b.Id
```

I've got that working just fine as a linq query:

```
var results = (from a in db.TableA 
               join b in db.TableB on a.Id equals b.Id
               select new MyObject {...}).ToList();
```

But now I want to add a left join to the mix as well.  In SQL:

```
SELECT
    ....
FROM
   TableA a
   JOIN TableB b on a.Id = b.Id
   LEFT JOIN TableC c on a.Id2 = c.Id2
```

I'm not sure how to handle this in the linq query.

Comment: Just add one line after your tableB join `join c in db.TableC on a.Id equals c.Id`

Comment: Will that behave like a LEFT JOIN and include all rows from TableA even if TableC has now matching records (c.ID2 is null)?

Comment: You know how to write [left outer join in LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_2), don't you? Just write it like if there is no other join in the query, e.g. `join c in TableC on a.Id2 equals c.Id2 into ac from c in ac.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: You've to select it `MyObject `

Comment: As always, first look at which navigation properties you could set up instead of using joins (`TableA.TableBs`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

SQL's `LEFT JOIN` concept is a pretty clunky abstraction when you think about what you're really trying to do. You really want, for every TableA entry, to have a list of TableC items associated with it, right?

LINQ uses a much simpler (IMO) way to represent this abstraction, because it has the concept of nested, hierarchical objects. The provider will generate a LEFT JOIN, but it'll also build the result into an object structure that's easy to work with.

```
var results = (from a in db.TableA 
               join b in db.TableB on a.Id equals b.Id
               select new MyObject {
                  ...
                  TableCEntries = 
                      from c in db.TableC
                      where c.Id == a.Id
                      select c     // or select specific values from c
               }).ToList();
```

If you really want your results flattened out the way they would be with a left outer join, you could do this:

```
var results = (from a in db.TableA 
               join b in db.TableB on a.Id equals b.Id
               from c in db.TableC
               where c.Id == a.Id
               select new MyObject {
                  ...
               }).ToList();
```

... but you wouldn't get any entries for TableA where there are no entries present for TableC. For that behavior you'd have to do ugly stuff with `group by`/`DefaultIfEmpty` as shown in [Ivan Stoev's link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_2).

Comment: This is not equivalent of the SQL `LEFT OUTER JOIN` though.

Comment: I see it (and agree in general), but the same can be said for the original OP query (the join between a and b). The choice between join and group join is up to the query writer. Gert Arnold's comment makes much more sense. Just a thought :) Btw, the last edit is incorrect  (with `where c.Id == a.Id`) - see my comment under the post.

Comment: for the second linq query, what does the sql profiler query look like?

Comment: @BlueLamp82: I don't know, you'd have to test it. But I'd guess it'd look like an inner join, then a left join, with a WHERE clause. Why do you ask?